# How to trigger/fire "oninput" events in Javascript/jQuery? jQuery('#iD').trigger("oninput")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, elementor

I am currently using an Elementor WordPress form plugin (MetForm) that is using `oninput` events to handle data submitted by users in their forms.

The issue is that I am passing data as parameters between pages in the URL but these can't be saved because they are not manually entered by the user when they land on the new page.

Their plugin as it is now requires users to interact with form elements to register the values.

```
jQuery('#iD').val();
```

**doesn't set a new value unless it is actually typed by the user.**

```
jQuery('#iD').trigger("oninput"); or jQuery('#iD').trigger("input");
```

**don't seem to work.**

It'd be very complicated for me to try to change their plugin and their support hasn't been responsive to my requests just yet.

**Is there a way I could manually trigger `oninput` event on a particular form element with a given ID to trick user input?** (*you can assume each form element has a separate ID as follows: #my-input1, #my-input2 etc.*)

---

**Please note I am not trying to handle the input. The user won't interact with an input I pre-fill for them. I am trying to trigger the `oninput` event to trick the form plugin to believe that's what happened so that the form values register when the form is submitted.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can manually add event listeners for inputs

Example:

```
const myInput = document.querySelector('#my-input1');
myInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    // code to run when oninput event is triggered on the input
})
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I am trying to trigger/fire "oninput" events so that the current form plugin registers all the values I have set with jQuery. User won't interact with inputs I prefill for them.

I am trying to have something like jQuery('#iD').trigger("oninput");

But this doesn't work.

Comment: i guess the mistake is from doing trigger("oninput")
do trigger("input")